# isset($_POST['submit']) doesn't work but $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" does

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get my button to work. It works with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` but not with `isset($_POST['submit'])`. The problem with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` is that it gives me multiple entries.

My code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $server_address = $_POST['submitServerIp'];
    $server_port = $_POST['submitServerPort'];


    $Query = new SourceQuery( );

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( $server_address, $server_port, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

        $data = $Query->GetInfo( );
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
        $error = true;
    }
    $Query->Disconnect( );
if($error == false)
{
    $errorMessage = "false";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Servers (ipaddress, port) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ipaddress, $port);

    $ipaddress = $_POST['submitServerIp'];
    $port = $_POST['submitServerPort'];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="container-fluid search-top">
    <div class="addContainer">
            <div class="addContainer col-sm-12">
                <p class="searchText"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($errorMessage);?></p>
                <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="submitServerIp" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Hostname/IP" style="border:0;">
                    <input type="text" name="submitServerPort" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Port" style="border:0;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
                            <span class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Can I not use the button the way I use it or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You need to add `name="submit"` to your submit button, this will solve your issue.

Comment: where is your name='submit' ?

Comment: omg... how did I forget this. It works. Cheers :) Still give two entries in the database though.

Comment: You're calling `$stmt->execute();` twice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `$_POST[KEY]` variable, the key is actually the `name` of the form element that you submitted, not the `value`.

To solve your issue, simply add `name="submit"` to your submit button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <span class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

As for the 2 entries in the database, you have an extra `execute()` function being called.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Servers (ipaddress, port) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ipaddress, $port);

    $ipaddress = $_POST['submitServerIp'];
    $port = $_POST['submitServerPort'];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

You should remove one of the above lines that say `$stmt->execute();`.

Comment: Thanks :) Facepalm. It fixed it, however, it still gives two entries into the database. Do you have any idea why it does that?

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. Thanks for the update. :D Saved me, been sitting with this for like 4 hours now.

Comment: @Leyer If mine (or any other) answer helped you, please check the little checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct. :)

Comment: I will thanks :) I tried before but it said I had to wait 10 min.

Comment: @Leyer Ah okay, gotcha. Cheers!